# Querying JIRA to Produce Counts of Issues by Different Type

Tags: jira, jql

Suppose I have the following JIRA filter.

`project = XXX AND resolution = Unresolved AND assignee in (EMPTY) ORDER BY Type asc, priority desc`

I use it to see all unassigned issues in a certain project and pull from for triage.

Every now-and-then, I need to know how many are in each Type, i.e., I actually want a count for each.

How could I modify this query to do that or write a new one that accomplishes the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that JQL isn't SQL - it just operates on tickets and returns lists of them for other parts of JIRA to consume, and doesn't really have a mechanism for counting results.

That said, you can use the JIRA REST API's `/search` endpoint along with `maxResults=0` to construct JQL queries for each `Type` you care about, and the endpoint will give you a `total` value for that ticket `Type`:

`https://jira.url/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project%20=%20XXX%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Unresolved%20AND%20assignee%20in%20%28EMPTY%29%20AND%20Type%20=%20Task&maxResults=0`

Results in this output for `Type=Task`:

```
{
    "startAt":0,
    "maxResults":0,
    "total":123,
    "issues":[]
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Do you know if JIRA allows one to monitor statistics on such things? That is, is there a page that could plot trends for these quantities or do I need to invent one myself and query these end-points?

Comment: Yeah - you'll need to make your JQL query into a Filter. Then, create a JIRA Dashboard, add the "Issue Statistics" gadget to it, and set the gadget's "Statistic Type" to "Issue Type" and choose your Filter to use as the gadget's basis.